# Does the function PQinitOpenSSL need to be called with libpq?

Tags: postgresql, openssl, libpq

I built the `libpq` static library using `USE_SSL=1` option. The syntax used was:

```
nmake.exe /f win32.mak USE_SSL=1 SSL_INC=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include SSL_LIB_PATH=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib
```

I am able to connect to DB server Using below command command

```
strconnection="hostaddr= machine_ip port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=require" ;

ptr_db_conn = (_TCHAR*)LPCTSTR(strconnection);
_conn = PQconnectdb(ptr_db_conn);
if ( PQstatus(m_conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
{    
    T_RESULT=FALSE;     
}
else
{
    T_RESULT=TRUE;
}

...
```

I am *not* using the two functions below with `sslmode=require` as discussed in documentation at [31.18.1. Client Verification of Server Certificates](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-ssl.html#LIBQ-SSL-CERTIFICATES):

1. void PQinitOpenSSL(int do_ssl, int do_crypto);
2. void PQinitSSL(int do_ssl);

Is it mandatory to use `PQinitOpenSSL` and `PQinitSSL` in postgreSQL 9.4?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it mandatory to use PQinitOpenSSL and PQinitSSL in postgreSQL 9.4?

The controlling document is [31.18.5. SSL Library Initialization](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-INITIALIZE):

> If your application initializes libssl and/or libcrypto libraries and
>   libpq is built with SSL support, you should call PQinitOpenSSL to tell
>   libpq that the libssl and/or libcrypto libraries have been initialized
>   by your application, so that libpq will not also initialize those
>   libraries.
>
> ```
> void PQinitOpenSSL(int do_ssl, int do_crypto);
> ```
>
> When do_ssl is non-zero, libpq will initialize the OpenSSL library
>   before first opening a database connection. When do_crypto is
>   non-zero, the libcrypto library will be initialized. By default (if
>   PQinitOpenSSL is not called), both libraries are initialized. When SSL
>   support is not compiled in, this function is present but does nothing.
>
> If your application uses and initializes either OpenSSL or its
>   underlying libcrypto library, you must call this function with zeroes
>   for the appropriate parameter(s) before first opening a database
>   connection. Also be sure that you have done that initialization before
>   opening a database connection.

So, if your application calls OpenSSL's `SSL_library_init` and `SSL_load_error_strings`, then you call Postgres' `PQinitOpenSSL` with 0's. Also see [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

If your application does not initialize the OpenSSL library, then you should call call Postgres' `PQinitOpenSSL` with non-0's.

The corner case appears to be: you include a second library such that the second library does in fact initialize the OpenSSL library. In this case, you  need to ensure the second library loads before `libpq`, and then your app calls `PQinitOpenSSL` with 0's because the second library invokes the initialization.

It also appears `PQinitSSL(int do_ssl)` with 0 or non-0 will work, too. There's no explicit `libcrypto` initialization in OpenSSL as far as I know, so `PQinitOpenSSL`'s `do_crypto` is simply not needed in this case. Other libraries may need it, and OpenSSL 1.1.0 may change that. But I don't think it applies in this case.